# Reading a table using macro and generating PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 3 columns, product ID, product name and region of origin (eg France, Italy, Japan etc). I have set up a data validation list based on region of origin.

I would like to select the region using the data validation list and utilise the macro to print to PDF (eg 20 products) based on the region.

Is there some post where I can reference as a start, doesn't have to be the full macro, just the rough structure is fine.

Comment: You can read these two post. [MrExcel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/macro-for-saving-visible-cells-as-pdf.762752/), [nhsexcel](http://nhsexcel.com/filtered-list-to-pdf/).

Answer (score 0):

To filter your data, record a macro and filter the data then stop the macro and show the code.

To export to pdf you can use this function

```
Sub ExportarPDF()

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="yourpathwithfilenameandextension.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```